# The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag was invalid

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-insights

I tried to enable Facebook Insights for my web. I added my page's `APP_ID` to `fb:admins` to enable every admin of my page to access Insights when logged into Facebook as Page. But when I try to save the dialog message appears:

```
The app ID "123,123,123,123,123" specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag was invalid.
```

I double checked my app ID and it's correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Only personal IDs are allowed** in the `fb:admins` meta tag. Application IDs won't work, even though they are actually valid (in contrary to what the error message says).

Optionally, it may also work with page_id:

```
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="395450240451647" />
```

The suggested `app_id`didn't work at all :(

Comment: `fb:page_id` was rejected by the sharing debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 23):

To link Domain Insights to an app rather than a user, you need to use the `fb:app_id` tag:

`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id" />`

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Comment: ~"12345667 is not a valid id" - in contrary page_id did work.

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: the link is broken, check updated link below

https://developers.facebook.com/search/?q=platforminsights%20domains&notfound=1

Answer (score 6):

You have to make public you app to start works.

Comment: Answers that guess at an underlying problem without first clarifying the question through comments tend to be risky, and unfortunately, since this question has an accepted answer that appears to contradict this, it doesn't appear the risk paid off.

Comment: This really can be the cause of exactly that message. Helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

error invalid fb:app_id is sometimes misleading. The account you are using to test this needs to be added into test users list of facebook app. Or try to test using the admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Few steps:
1- check your robots.txt, you shouldn't block: facebookexternalhit.
Example:

```
User-agent: facebookexternalhit
Disallow:
```

2- check if your app is **not in development** App Mode: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<your_app_id>/dashboard/

Answer (score -1):

Sometime your facebook information already crawl by facebook and it will be **cache**

You need to clear there cache to test again

You can access this link : **https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/**

paste your clink you want to test

Click **Crawl again**

Comment: Can I ask you if that I'm getting the error in the debugging tool! (Invalid App ID
The specified 'fb:app:id' property is not a valid app ID.)  Not sure why as I'm getting images and url and Open Graph properties ok so I'm able to share. pages to facebook but having to use Tagz to do this process. I'm just confused if I'm setup ok with it like this.