# Do I need to put fb:amins & fb:app id meta tags to every page of my website or puting them on one page would be enogh?

Tags: facebook

i want to get insights for my website,i'm talking about these meta tags 

 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put those tags on every page.
Please note that you might want to use

```
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="395450240451647" />
```

As some are having problems getting it to work with app_id

[The app ID specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag was invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347937/the-app-id-specified-within-the-fbapp-id-meta-tag-was-invalid)

Comment: can i use both of them fb:app id and fb:admins id on my root page?

Comment: yes. but it's configured, correctly, you shouldn't need to. If the admin is already admin of the app, you just need to set the app_id (or page_id). If you don't have an app id then you can use the admins. Hope this helps.